# PHP Memcached Plug n Play

Tags: php, memcached

I'm searching google and it seems i cant find an exact answer.

I'm done installing the PHP Memcached, I can view it in phpinfo() and I was able to test the connection as per php.net manual.

My question is simple. Do I need to recode all my PHP files in order to take advantage of memcached or its a plug n play type? Is there a way to check if the PHP is actually using the memcached and not pooling same data/report from database?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you expect to happen, now that `memcached` is installed and configured for use with PHP?

Comment: I think the question is does PHP *use* memcached once it is installed in some *automatic* way. Which I believe the simple answer is *No*.

Comment: What Jason says is on the money. You need to rebuild your application to make use of Memcache, there is no automatic way to simply speed up your app with it. If you're looking for something like that, you want a bytecode cache / precompiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memcached (installed from PECL) is a shared library. If it's enable, you should be able to starting using it *within* your application -- right away.

#### Check if it's enabled

```
shell~> php -m | grep memcached
```

#### Do I need to recode all my PHP files in order to take advantage of memcached?

Yes. Memcached extends the memcache protocol/API to a PHP object. You'll have to determine what get's cached within your application. With objects, this is easily done be extending Memcached.

```
 class MyCacheObject extends Memcached
```

#### Is there a way to check if the PHP is actually using the memcached?

You can [telnet](/questions/tagged/telnet) directly to the Memcached server, and see what's stored

```
shell ~> telnet localhost 11211
telnet~> stats items
```

#### And not pooling same data/report from database?

That's up to you. Some people will use Memcache to store results from the database, PHP Objects, or indexes/queries to find additional data from the database. This boils down to what exactly you would like to cache. I prefer to store results from the database; such that, repetitive DB calls are reduced.

Comment: The (kind of ambiguous) remark about extending `Memcached` with `class MyCacheObject extends Memcached` could lead a reader to believe that that will 'magically' do something with that object. Just to be clear: it is NOT an interface / property which makes it self-storing in memcache, it is interface to memcache with which you'll have to code the storing/retrieving and it's logic yourself.

Comment: On a side note: I rarely store intermediate results (PHP objects and the like) in memcached. For websites, if I'm caching already, I just opt for storing the rendered HTML when possible, takes even more load of the server & the same rules for expiring still apply.